# Proof by contradiction with 9 boxes

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can i re-write for a better presentation if it is correct, if not what are the errors:
Prove the following by contradiction: If 100 balls are placed in 9 boxes, some box contains 12 or more balls.

> ¬$p$ /implies If 100 balls are placed in 9 boxes no box contains 12 or more.
>   
>   100/9= 11 R1
>   Therefore some box must contain 12 or more.
>    ¬$p$= false, Thus  $p$ is true

Comment: You have the right idea in mind. Using logical symbols and abbreviations such as $100/9=11R1$ makes things less clear, not clearer.

Answer (score 2):

proof by contradiction.

suppose no box contains as many as $12$. then the total number $N$ of balls satisfies:
$$
100 = N \le 11 \times 9 = 99
$$